# csh cd alias: how to eliminate error when no parameter is supplied

Tags: linux, unix, shell, alias, csh

I am familiar with bash, but my works require csh. in my .cshrc, I created this alias:

```
alias cd 'cd \!:1; ls -l'
```

It works very well except for one case: when I cd without any parameter:

```
cd
```

In which case, I get the "**Bad ! arg selector**" error. How do I eliminate this error? I appreciate any help to overcome this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using \!:1 to select the first argument, use \!* to select all the arguments.

This works fine for there being no arguments.  It will throw a wobbly if you provide more than one argument though.

Comment: Your solution works well as discussed. Thank you Matt.